# Apartment in Munich

Tags: germany, accommodation, munich

I'm a married man looking for an apartment to live with my wife from February 2014 until April 2014.  How can I find an apartment for this time period?

Comment: Just in case you are wondering: Munich is the most expensive city in Germany and the price per m^2 is currently at least 15€, but can go up to 30€.

Answer (score 7):

If you don't speak German, [Airbnb](https://www.airbnb.com/) is your best bet. For the period you mention, they feature some 150 entire apartments that are suitable for 2 persons.

Comment: Note that a very recent court decision ( http://www.fr-online.de/wirtschaft/bgh-urteil-zu-airbnb---co--untervermieten-an-touristen-wird-schwieriger-,1472780,25835460.html ) will probably drastically reduce the Airbnb offers in Germany - the federal court decided that a permission from the landlord for subletting does not cover tourist stays.

Comment: @MichaelBorgwardt May be not: http://publicpolicy.airbnb.com/court-decision-germany/

Comment: @Karlson: they're not being entirely honest there. The federal court decision is about subletting, while the government statement they refer to is about a local regulation's impact on providing living space that's also used to work in. Completely irrelevant. And the second point - Airbnb "asks hosts to seek permission from their landlord" - but does nothing to ensure this is actually done.

Comment: Let's wait and see.

Comment: Why does the Airbnb statement translate "Abgeordneter" (which means "member of parliament") with "government official"? This is misleading. And the other linked Airbnb statement cites only spokespersons of parliamentary groups of the local parliament of Berlin and their opinions, which has no immediate legal impact. So I agree with @MichaelBorgwardt

Answer (score 4):

If you are searching for an unfurnished apartment, this is the most popular site in Germany:

http://www.immobilienscout24.de

Otherwise, you can check Craigslist Munich for apartment listings, almost all of which are furnished. Alternately run a simple search on Google for "Furnished apartments Munich" and you will see lots of different companies providing basically the same service.

**Edit: I misread the original question, the OP is only staying for a very short amount of time.  My advice is best suited for people staying over a year.**

Comment: True, they have furnished flats and apartments but for shorter rentals (3 months or less) this site is, according to my experience, not so terrible.

Comment: Woops, For some reason, I mistakenly read the dates as 2014-2016. The OP should absolutely use AirBNB.  My advice is best for people staying long term, 1 year or more.

Answer (score 3):

I would also recommend [HouseTrip.com](http://housetrip.com). We used it to find apartments in Budapest, Prague and Vienna and had a great experience overall! I was impressed by how flexible the search feature was (i.e., we were able to search for centrally located apartments that can sleep 6 people and that include WiFi and laundry).

Comment: Their site is hard to click about on a phone.